# How do I call a defined function in another Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code in languageSwitcher.js

```
$('#selectlanguage').change(AnyFunctionfromAnotherJsFile);
```

I do not want to make AnyFunctionfromAnotherJsFile as global function.

Comment: the ‘setButtonText’ has to be in the global scope... anyway You can do better to avoid that, use a namespace

Comment: What does `setButtonText` do? Does it just change the appearance of a button based on the language chosen, if so, you would be better served creating different `.CSS` files for each language type and once the language is chosen, load up the correct `.CSS` file that correlates to the language chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This waits for on change and runs a function that calls setButtonText();

```
$('#selectlanguage').change(function(){
   setButtonText();
});
```

Comment: setButtonText in another Javascript .. i may not able to call setButtonTex(); that is what my question.. call a function from other file

Comment: @12345GG As long as the script file which has the function is loaded before the call to it, it will work.

Comment: @RyanWilson Thats whats confusing me, if its in another file I would assume its  already rendered with the HTML? What am I missing

Comment: @GrandIQ Nothing that I can tell. I think what you provided is relevant, I'm not sure if the OP is sure about how to ask this question. And yes, it would mean that the script tag would need to be included in the page or a page it inherits from before being able to call it.

Comment: @RyanWilson Unless its an IIFE function and its a plugin?

Comment: @GrandIQ Now I'm getting confused, lol. It appears to me that they want to add a change event to the drop down, then call a function which is not part of the script which is attaching the event handler.

Comment: Yes..that is what i am asking